# Do properties implicitly initialise variables?

Tags: c#

I found this code on a PDF tutorial:

```
public class Chien
{
    public static int NombreDeChiens { get; set; }
    private string prenom;

    public Chien(string prenomDuChien)
    {
        prenom = prenomDuChien;
        NombreDeChiens++;
    }

    public void Aboyer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wouaf ! Je suis " + prenom);
    }
}
```

There is no initialization in this code though in the `constructor` there is this incrementation. So how is it possible?

Comment: Fields gets initialized to default unless specified otherwise. This property is syntactic sugar but still have a backing field.

Comment: There is default values for each data type, For int dataType default value is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A property is nothing but a field wrapped with a get- and a set-method. As fields *do* have an initial value, properties also do.

E.g. the following code:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

is translated to something like this by the compiler:

```
private int _myProperty;   // the actual name of the field defers and is only known by the compiler
public int get_MyProperty() { return this._myProperty; }
public void set_MyProperty(int value) { this._myProperty = value; }
```

So the question boils down to "have **fields** a default-value"? The answer to this question is yes, they do: `null` for reference-types and the default-value for all structs, e.g. `0` for `int`, or `0f` for `float`.